# Why the width of my h1 in desktop's browser is different from it's width on iPhone?

Tags: html, css, iphone, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm writing a responsive webpage, and first of all I added the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">` tag, so I guess it has the same behaviour on desktop and smartphone devices. The little problem is that my `<h1>`'s width is renderer in a different way. I explain better.

Here's my header's code:

```
<header>
   <h1>...</h1>
</header>
```

whit it's CSS code:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
   header {
      min-height: 100vh;
   }

   header h1 {
      width: 70%;
      font-size: 2em;
   }
}
```

Whit the `viewport` tag the look of the webpage should be the same, both using a smartphone or resizing the web page. I see that when I resize the desktop's browser window to an iPhone's size, what I look is that there's no break line (the title is all in one line), instead using an iPhone the title has a break line. I don't understand this, since the behaviour should be the same.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `width: auto` or `width: 100vw`

Comment: A little explanation would boost the quality of your answer.

Comment: Instead of using em in font-size vw can be used

Comment: This doesn't resolve my problem: with these settings, the `<h1>` tag only will have a full width of 100%. Instead, I still don't understand why if I resize the desktop browser window I obtain a different behaviour from that of my iPhone browser.